# (Inverse) mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ to subsets of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-numbers, integers

There's the usual mapping $2^\mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{R}_{[0,1)}$ (where $2^\mathbb{N}$ denotes the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$) given by $x\in2^\mathbb{N}\mapsto\sum_{i\in x}\frac{1}{2^i}\in\mathbb{R}$. I'm interested in the inverse $\mathbb{R}_{[0,1)}\mapsto2^\mathbb{N}$, i.e., given $r\in\mathbb{R}$, what's the corresponding $x_r\in2^\mathbb{N}$ that generates it? (Note: I'm just guessing appropriate tags)

Is that $x_r\in2^\mathbb N$ explicitly constructible? Or its characteristic function, i.e., for $r\in\mathbb{R}_{[0,1)}$ and $x_r\mapsto r$, $\chi_r(i)=\left\{{1\ if\ i\in x_r\atop0\ otherwise}\right.$?

Also, poset ordering question as follows. While it's clear that $x_1\subseteq x_2\Longrightarrow r_{x_1}\le r_{x_2}$, what about the inverse? That is, $r_{x_1}\le r_{x_2}\overset?\Longrightarrow x_1\subseteq x_2$. And if not true, got an explicit counterexample?

**__Edit__**

Firstly, thanks very much Lubin, Manmaid, Ross, Daniel for your elaborate and thoughtful answers/comments. I haven't had time to fully digest everything, but one apparent take-away is the pesky appearance of infinite subsets. And that's got to be an unnecessary artifact: there's no reason why, say, $\frac13=.333\ldots=\sum_{i\in x}\frac1{2^i}$, should require some stupid-large $x\subseteq\mathbb N$ for its representation, whereas the information content of $\frac13$ is ultimately pretty minimal.

And it was Ross' mention of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational that suggested the culprit. It's the explicit "***base 2***" representation/expansion which I naively introduced in the above question that I'm now thinking is the problem. Daniel's answer introduces a slightly different expansion, but the same underlying problem remains.

So here's a tentative conjecture for a more general representation, which hopefully maps "simple $r\in\mathbb R$'s" to "simple $x_r\in2^\mathbb N$'s". But the representation algorithm's somewhat more complicated than Daniel's or mine above. And the meaning of the subset-order $x_1\subseteq x_2$ isn't at all obvious.

Consider the usual pair enumeration https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function whereby $\mathbb{N\times N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$. And we can then iterate that for $\mathbb{N^3\rightarrow N}$ (or any finite power, but we just need $3$). So consider some $x\in2^\mathbb N$ and interpret every $i\in x$ as three-component $i=(j,k,m)\mapsto j/k^m$. That is, we decompose $r\in\mathbb R$ into rational components of the form $j/k^m\in\mathbb Q$, with any mix of ***base k***'s that's convenient.

Now, as Lubin and Ross previously pointed out, it's **still** possible to represent, e.g., $\frac12=\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^3}+\cdots$. So we need some formal way to distinguish a "canonical representation" $\frac12=\frac1{2^1}$. So I haven't figured that out, nor how to interpret the poset order $x_1\subseteq x_2$, etc.

But I believe the premise, that these pesky infinite subsets should go away (except for transcendental reals) is necessary for any sensible $\mathbb R_{[0,1)}\Leftrightarrow2^\mathbb N$. As per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_domain#Explanation, the poset order is an information order, so you shouldn't have teensy-weensy elements on one side of the $\Leftrightarrow$ corresponding to biggy-wiggy elements on the other side. Somehow, that's got to go. But is the preceding conjecture really the simplest or most straightforward way?

**__Edit#2__**
Reply (too lengthy for comment) to Ross's comment below, "With your edit I understand even less what you are asking..."

Yeah, sorry about that. In a preceding comment replying to you, I mentioned

> "Actually, the constructible bijection's for an explicit correspondence between the universal domains $\mathcal P\omega\Leftrightarrow\mathcal U$ ( where the rhs denotes the universal interval domain, as per https://books.google.com/books?id=epb39s2wgt0C&pg=PA162 )

And I'd thought I'd solved that to my own satisfaction, modulo the kind of bijection I asked for here. That bijection's ultimate purpose is thus a correspondence between sets of integers on the $\mathcal P\omega\equiv2^\mathcal N$ side and half-open real intervals with rational endpoints on the $\mathcal U$ side.

By the way, note that in that $\mathcal U$ domain, any real is the lub of intervals including it. Put another way, the real line corresponds to the collection of total (aka maximal) elements of $\mathcal U$ wrt reverse-inclusion ordering. That is, the smaller the interval, the more information you have about the real it refers to.

The upshot is that for the purposes of this question, I was perfectly happy discussing rational approximations to reals. As per a comment to Manmaid,

> ...Actually, I simplified the question by neglecting to discuss intervals. If you represent $r_{x_n}\in\mathbb R$ by an $x_n=\lbrace i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n\rbrace$ containing the first $n$ smallest $i$'s in order, with $i_n$ the largest among them, then you're really representing an interval $[r_{x_n},r_{x_n}+1/2^{i_n})$.

So every time I mentioned "real", my underlying thinking was really "interval" as an element of that $\mathcal U$ domain. But I didn't think it necessary to mention that in the context of the original question. I thought I just needed the requested bijection wrt reals, and then everything would just fall into place wrt $\mathcal U$.

So where'd that go wrong? The bijection's subject to a pesky additional constraint wrt that reverse-inclusion information ordering, which it must respect. Suppose the bijection's $b:\mathcal U\rightarrow2^{\mathcal N}$,
and write $u_1\sqsubseteq u_2$ for the $u_1,u_2\in\mathcal U$ poset order, and $x_1\subseteq x_2$ for the $x_1,x_2\in2^\mathcal N$ order. Then $b$ must satisfy $u_1\sqsubseteq u_2\Longrightarrow b(u_1)\subseteq b(u_2)$. (and given that $b$'s one-to-one, the arrow has to go both ways)

And that didn't just automatically happen like I'd expected (more accurately, I didn't even think about it until I noticed it wasn't happening). And that unexpected problem got me asking additional stuff seemingly unrelated to the original question, which I guess accounts for your "understand even less what you are asking" remark. (and I hope this helps clear that up a little)

Comment: Don't you think the map you gave $2^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}_{[0,1]}$is bijective

Comment: @MANMAID yes -- but that's not  a constructive statement. While it's clear how to explicitly construct $r\in\mathbb{R}$ corresponding to a given $x\in2^\mathbb{N}$ (exactly like I showed in the question), how do you inversely construct $x$ given $r$? That's the question, as asked in the first sentence of second paragraph.

Comment: @JohnForkosh:  It is not bijective, as Lubin shows, so there is not an inverse function.

Comment: @RossMillikan See my comment to Lubin, below.

Comment: If you are programming it (as in your comment to Lubin) you are presumably working in floats, not in the reals.  For issues like this they are wildly different.  Floats have a finite expansion and there are only finitely many of them.  How are you taking $x$ unless it is a float?

Comment: @RossMillikan Okay, you kind of caught me there. Yes, I will be programming it, but only for some illustrative purposes. Actually, the constructible bijection's for an explicit correspondence between the unversal domains $\mathcal{P}\omega\Leftrightarrow\mathcal{U}$ ( where the rhs denotes the universal interval domain, as per https://books.google.com/books?id=epb39s2wgt0C&pg=PA162 )

Comment: With your edit I understand even less what you are asking.  The basic correspondence of numbers with their binary expansions works for all the numbers except the dyadic fractions, which is most of them.  Most reals don't have anything simple about them.  Now you are focused only on the rationals, but not all of them can be written as $j/k^m$

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry about being confusing. I added an additional Edit#2 above, trying to de-confuse by putting the question's intent in its fuller domain theory context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}_{[0,1)}$ consider these steps. Let's call it ***Structure***:

> 1. Calculate $2x$, if $2x\geq 1$, then  fix first number $1$, and if $2x<1$, fix first number $0$. Now calculate $\{2x\}$, the fraction part of $2x$.
> 2. Calculate $2\{2x\}$, if $2\{2x\}\geq 1$, then  fix second number $1$, and if $2\{2x\}<1$, fix second number $0$. Now calculate $\{2\{2x\}\}$, the fraction part of $2\{2x\}$.
>
> Continue this process. Finally you will get an element of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

**The construction of a bijective function:**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_{[0,1)}\rightarrow 2^{\mathbb{N}}$

Suppose $x\in \mathbb{R}_{[0,1)}$ is not of the form $\frac{n}{2^m}$, where $n<2^m$ is odd natural number and $m\in \mathbb{N}$, then $f(x)=$ the final sequence you get from the ***Structure*** for $x$.

Now if $x\in \mathbb{R}_{[0,1)}$ is of the form $\frac{n}{2^m}$, where $n<2^m$ is odd natural number and $m\in \mathbb{N}$, then values looks like this:
$$\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{4}\space\space\frac{3}{4}\\\frac{1}{8}\space\space\frac{3}{8}\space\space\frac{5}{8}\space\space\frac{7}{8}\\\frac{1}{16}\space\space\frac{3}{16}\space\space\frac{5}{16}\space\space\frac{7}{16}\space\space\frac{9}{16}\space\space\frac{11}{16}\space\space\frac{13}{16}\space\space\frac{15}{16}\\\dots\\\dots\\\dots$$

First fix $f(\frac{1}{2})=(1,1,1,\dots)$. Now calculate the sequence you get from ***Structure*** for taking $x=1/2$. Surely you get $(1,0,0,0,\dots)$. Now fix $f(\frac{1}{4})=(1,0,0,0,\dots)$ and $f(\frac{3}{4})=(0,1,1,1,\dots)$. Again calculate the sequence you get from ***Structure*** for taking $x=1/4$ and $x=3/4$. Sequence you get are $(0,1,0,0,0,\dots)$ and $(1,1,0,0,0,\dots)$ respectively. You immediately fix $f(\frac{1}{8})=(0,1,0,0,0,\dots)$, $f(\frac{3}{8})=(0,0,1,1,1,\dots)$, $f(\frac{5}{8})=(1,1,0,0,0,\dots)$ and $f(\frac{7}{8})=(1,0,1,1,1,\dots)$.Continue in this way and finally you have $f$ is a bijective mapping.

Comment: Thanks MANMAID. Yeah, by inspection that seems to do the trick -- and I'll be programming it, at which time we'll know for sure:). And double-yeah about "finite". Actually, I simplified the question by neglecting to discuss intervals. If you represent $r$ by an $x_n=\lbrace i_1,i_2,\ldots i_n\rbrace$ containing the first $n$ smallest $i$'s in order, with $i_n$ the largest among them, then you're really representing an interval $[r_{x_n},r_{x_n}+1/2^{i_n})$.

Comment: This is wrong.  You will never generate the sequences in $2^{\Bbb N}$ that end in an infinite series of $1$s.  If $x=\frac 12$ you will generate $1,0,0,0,\ldots$ and no real will generate $0,1,1,1,1,\ldots$.

Comment: @RossMillikan $.5=.49999.....$ (I don't know how to write dot on top of a number)

Comment: @RossMillikan $0.5=0.4\dot{9}$

Comment: That is true and is essentially the issue your answer misses.  If you follow through your algorithm with $x=0.5_{10}=0.1_2$ you will generate the sequence $1,0,0,0,0,\ldots$ which is a valid binary expansion for the number.  The problem is that no real number will generate the expansion $0,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots$ if we follow your algorithm, so it does not generate a bijection between the reals in $[0,1)$ and the binary sequences.  There are computable algorithms that do this, but you have to deal with the binary expansions that equate to the same reals.

Comment: What are you saying sir @RossMillikan ... clearly $0.4\dot{9}_{10}=0.0\dot{1}_2$ and $0.5_{10}=0.1_2$, then clearly the counterexample you are giving is not valid. I read about this bijection 7 yrs ago in [Elementary Number Theory - David M. Burton](http://184.168.171.185/BOOKS/DVD%201/Elementary%20Number%20Theory%20-%20David%20M.%20Burton.pdf). What I did is obviously not wrong!!!

Comment: Both those statements are true, but they represent the same real.  If $x=0.5_{10}$ your algorithm generates the sequence $1,0,0,0,\ldots$  If you express the same $x$ as $0.4\dot{9}_{10}$ you will still generate $1,0,0,0,\ldots$.  There is no real that will generate $0,1,1,1,1,\ldots$

Comment: @RossMillikan take a sequence $a_1=0.49, a_2=0.499,\dots$, in general $a_n=0.499\dots 9$ ($n\space 9$s) in base $10$. Now generate the algoritm I gave on $a_1,a_2,\dots$. Generated value of $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ is $0,1,1,\dots$. So the algo generates $0,1,1,\dots$.

Comment: @RossMillikan (and MANMAID) So what, if any, would be the significance of factoring $2^\mathbb N$ into equivalence classes $x\equiv_ry\overset{def}\Leftrightarrow r_x=r_y$. For example, $1,0,0,0\ldots\equiv_r0,1,1,1,\ldots$, and syntactically, that's just swapping $0\leftrightarrow1$ symbols, which is ultimately meaningless (although there's usually a meaningful denotational semantics difference). And granted, Ross's "$a/2^n$" remark in previous comment involves more than $0\leftrightarrow1$ syntax, might there be some more subtle interpretation of $2^\mathbb N$ corresponding to $\equiv_r$?

Comment: @JohnForkosh for reals that are not dyadic rationals you would group $x$ and $1-x$ into the same equivalence class.  That is a step backward if you are trying to find a bijection.  You want to start by taking care of most of the sequences by matching them up to a real.  Then you need to take care of the corner cases.  The usual way to do that is to push the problem down the line.  As long as the line is infinite you don't come to the end and all is well.  See my answer.

Comment: @JohnForkosh yet I do no understand why this algo will not give every element in $2^{\mathbb{N}}$

Comment: @MANMAID that last comment should be addressed to Ross??? Yeah, I didn't completely follow his conclusion, either. But he says "see my answer", which I'm not seeing yet. Maybe wait till he posts it, and then see if that clears things up (or post a followup comment there if not).

Comment: @JohnForkosh please check my the edit! I think it is perfect now!!! Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383178/a-serious-problem-in-bijection-in-a-algo)

Comment: Thanks again, Manmaid. I posted an "answer" in the other question you started, with the code (and some examples) I mentioned I'd write.

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if you mean for $\Bbb N$ to be $\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$.
Naively, a function has an inverse only if it’s one-to-one. But your map $2^{\Bbb N}\to[0,1\rangle$, is not one-to-one, since $\frac12$ is the image both of $(1,0,0,\cdots)$ (i.e. the function that’s zero everywhere but at $n=1$) and $(0,1,1,1,1,\cdots)$ (i.e. the function that’s $1$ everywhere but at $n=1$. In more familiar terms, $\frac12=\frac14+\frac18+\frac1{16}+\cdots$
This is just the familiar fact that every real with a terminating decimal (or terminating binary expansion) has a different, nonterminating expansion.

The moral? You can not form an inverse to your function.

Comment: But is $\frac12$ the unique exception? Given any subset $x \in 2^\mathbb N$ and its corresponding $r_x \in\mathbb R$, it's clear that the set complement, call it $x^\prime=\mathbb N\setminus x$, corresponds to $r_{x^\prime}=1-r_x$. So your set complement is $ (1,0,0,0,\cdots)^\prime=(0,1,1,1,\cdots)$ and then $\frac12=1-\frac12$ is the unique case. (P.S. yeah, my exact wording implies the natural numbers $\lbrace1,2,3,\cdots\rbrace$ without $0$. But in reality I'm including $0$ and considering $1-\mathbb{R}_{[0,2)}=\mathbb{R}_{[-1,1)}$. No big difference.)

Comment: No any rational of the form $\frac a{2^n}$ has this problem because they have a terminating binary expansion and another one that ends in all ones.  It is a countably infinite set, which can be dealt with to make a computable bijection.  The Schroeder-Bernstein-Cantor theorem guarantees that a bijection exists and one approach is to use it to construct the bijection.

Comment: @Lubin what are you saying is not right (how did you get 2 upvotes, I don't know!) You are saying $x$ and $\lim_{\epsilon\to\ 0} (x-\epsilon)$ are different because of their representation. How will you say $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$ is bijective using same logic!!

Comment: @RossMillikan Right, I overlooked that "universal exception" (if you'll pardon the oxymoron:). But thanks for that Schroeder-Bernstein-Cantor reference, which I wasn't aware of, and which seems to adequately establish the bijection existence. I think the two distinct cases you mention simply correspond to choosing between $<$ and $\le$ in MANMAID's algorithm. (And I think we'll be choosing the finite/terminating case.)

Comment: @JohnForkosh:  S-B-C establishes that there is a bijection.  It does not guarantee that the bijection respects order.  I can see a simple patch to make a bijection, but it will not make the order on the reals agree with the lexicographic order on the sequences.  I haven't found a proof that there is not an order preserving bijection, but I strongly suspect there is not one.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for addressing the "order preseving" part of original question (which seems to have gotten otherwise lost). As per my preceding comment back to you regarding $\mathcal P\omega\Leftrightarrow\mathcal U$ domain theory, the fact that they're both universal domains suggests (at least to me) there should be an order-preserving bijection. Being universal, each is a subdomain of the other, whereby the composition of their respective retracts should just be the identity (though that's just an intuitive conclusion on my part).

Comment: We can use the density of the reals to show there is no order preserving bijection.  In the lexicographic order of sequences there is nothing between $0,1,1,1,1,1\ldots$ and $1,0,0,0,0,\ldots$.  Each of those must correspond to a real and there will be a real between those two, so the order is not preserved.

Comment: @RossMillikan Okay, I'll have to think/read about that in much more detail. It seems to suggest that the total elements of $\mathcal{P}\omega,\mathcal{U}$ have no one-to-one correspondence, since each such element is just maximal in its own poset order. And what you're saying (I think) is that the two orderings can go off in "different directions" when starting from the lub of a given subset. So something's goofy, although that goofy thing may very well be my own thinking (to be determined).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the Cantor set $C=\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2f(n)3^{-n}: f\in F\}$ where $F$ is the set of all functions $f:\mathbb N\to \{0,1\}.$ For $x\in C$ there is a unique $f_x\in F$ such that $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2f_x(n)3^{-n},$ and $f_x=f_y\implies x=y.$

So for $x\in C$ let $G(x)=\{n\in \mathbb N: f_x(n)=1\}.$ For $x\in [0,1]$ \ $C$ let $G(x)$ be any member of $2^{\mathbb N}$ that you want, as $G:C\to 2^{\mathbb N}$ is already surjective.

Remark: $G$ is not injective, but neither is the surjection $H(x)=\sum_{i\in x}2^{-i}$ from $2^{\mathbb N}$ to $[0,1]$ in your Q. For example $H(\mathbb N$ \ $\{1\})=H(\{1\})=1/2.$

Answer (score 2):

We can construct an explicit bijection between $[0,1)$ and $2^{\Bbb N}$ as follows.  As long as $x$ is not a rational of the form $\frac a{2^n}$ with $1 \le a \lt 2^n$ it has a unique binary expansion so we can match them up.  One problem is that numbers of the form $\frac a{2^n}$ have two binary representations, one ending in all $0$s and one ending in all $1$s.  The one with all $0$s starts with the finite expansion of $a$ and the one with all $1$s starts with the finite expansion of $a-1$, both padded on the left with zeros to make $n$ bits.  The other problem is that we have excluded $1$ from the real interval so we have nothing to match with $1,1,1,1,\ldots $

Given a rational of the form $\frac a{2^n}$ with $a$ odd so the fraction is in lowest terms, let $m$ be the minimum value so that $2^m \gt a$.  If $n-m$ is even we will make a correspondence to a sequence with an infinite run of $0$s while if $n-m$ is odd we will make a correspondence to a sequence with an infinite run of $1$s.  We let $k=\lfloor \frac {n-m}2 \rfloor$, then the real $\frac a{2^n}$ corresponds to the binary expansion of $\frac a{2^{n-k}}$ using the terminating version if $k$ is even and the infinite $1$s if $k$ is odd.  Finally if $a=1$ we push all the expansions down by $1$ to make $1,1,1,1,\ldots $ correspond to $\frac 12$.

Comment: Sir, I posted a proof-verification [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383178/a-serious-problem-in-bijection-in-a-algo). I think it is finally complete! (Also you can see the edited answer here)