# A serious problem in Bijection in a Algo

Tags: proof-verification, problem-solving, binary

*If you have seen this part before, ignore the first part and jump to "Change of the algo here" section*

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383021/inverse-mapping-from-mathbbr-to-subsets-of-mathbbn/2383056#2383056) I gave this following Algorithm to generate every element of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ with given a value $x\in \mathbb{R}_{[0,1)}$

let $x\in \mathbb{R}_{[0,1)}$.

1. If $x=1$, then note that $1_{10}=0.\dot{9}_{10}$ and $0.\dot{9}_{10}=0.\dot{1}_2$
2. Otherwise calculate $2x$, if $2x\geq 1$, then  fix first number $1$, and if $2x<1$, fix first number $0$. Now calculate $\{2x\}$, the fraction part of $2x$.
3. Calculate $2\{2x\}$, if $2\{2x\}\geq 1$, then  fix second number $1$, and if $2\{2x\}<1$, fix second number $0$. Now calculate $\{2\{2x\}\}$, the fraction part of $2\{2x\}$.

Continue this process. Finally you will get an element of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

I made this part invisible since this part is not needed after the edit:

> **But** one user(Ross Millikam) argued that I ca not generate $0,1,1,1,\dots$ using this algo! So I wrote "take a sequence $a_1=0.49, a_2=0.499,\dots$, in general $a_n=0.499\dots 9$($n\space 9$s)in base $10$. Now generate the algorithm I gave on $a_1,a_2,\dots$. Generated value of $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ is $0,1,1,\dots$.  So the algo generates $0,1,1,\dots$."

**Is my argument wrong? Is this algo really do represent the bijection between $\mathbb{R}_{[0,1]}$ and $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ ?**

One important things to note:

1. $0.4\dot{9}_{10}=0.0\dot{1}_2=0.1_2=0.5_{10}$

Please, I do not need a alternative answer!!! The link gave already have plenty of that!

---

### Change of the algo here:

---

First, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}_{[0,1)}$ consider these steps. Let's call it ***Structure***:

> 1. Calculate $2x$, if $2x\geq 1$, then  fix first number $1$, and if $2x<1$, fix first number $0$. Now calculate $\{2x\}$, the fraction part of $2x$.
> 2. Calculate $2\{2x\}$, if $2\{2x\}\geq 1$, then  fix second number $1$, and if $2\{2x\}<1$, fix second number $0$. Now calculate $\{2\{2x\}\}$, the fraction part of $2\{2x\}$.
>
> Continue this process. Finally you will get an element of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

**The construction of a bijective function:**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_{[0,1)}\rightarrow 2^{\mathbb{N}}$

Suppose $x\in \mathbb{R}_{[0,1)}$ is not of the form $\frac{n}{2^m}$, where $n<2^m$ is odd natural number and $m\in \mathbb{N}$, then $f(x)=$ the final sequence you get from the ***Structure***.

Now if $x\in \mathbb{R}_{[0,1)}$ is of the form $\frac{n}{2^m}$, where $n<2^m$ is odd natural number and $m\in \mathbb{N}$, then values looks like this:
$$\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{4}\space\space\frac{3}{4}\\\frac{1}{8}\space\space\frac{3}{8}\space\space\frac{5}{8}\space\space\frac{7}{8}\\\frac{1}{16}\space\space\frac{3}{16}\space\space\frac{5}{16}\space\space\frac{7}{16}\space\space\frac{9}{16}\space\space\frac{11}{16}\space\space\frac{13}{16}\space\space\frac{15}{16}\\\dots\\\dots\\\dots$$

First fix $f(\frac{1}{2})=(1,1,1,\dots)$. Now calculate the sequence you get from ***Structure*** for taking $x=1/2$. Surely you get $(1,0,0,0,\dots)$. Now fix $f(\frac{1}{4})=(1,0,0,0,\dots)$ and $f(\frac{3}{4})=(0,1,1,1,\dots)$. Again calculate the sequence you get from ***Structure*** for taking $x=1/4$ and $x=3/4$. Sequence you get are $(0,1,0,0,0,\dots)$ and $(1,1,0,0,0,\dots)$ respectively. You immediately fix $f(\frac{1}{8})=(0,1,0,0,0,\dots)$, $f(\frac{3}{8})=(0,0,1,1,1,\dots)$, $f(\frac{5}{8})=(1,1,0,0,0,\dots)$ and $f(\frac{7}{8})=(1,0,1,1,1,\dots)$.Continue in this way and finally you have $f$ is a bijective mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is wrong because $\lim_n a_n = 1/2$, which binary digits are $0.1$ The $k$-th binary digit of number $x$ and the digits after it are *discontinuous* at $x$ if $x$ is a fraction $n/2^k$ where $n$ is an odd number.

Your algorithm simply computes the sequence of binary digits of real numbers, and as such, it cannot generate sequences that end up with $111...$.

Edit **after your last algorithm update with "the structure"**

I think the argument is now fundamentally **correct**. The function $f$ now maps every number that is not of the form $\frac{m}{2^k}$ to the sequence of its binary digits. You are left with countably many numbers without an image, namely the $\frac{m}{2^k}$ (with $m$ odd) and also countably many missing elements of $2^\mathbb{N}$, namely the sequences that end with an constant sequence of $0$ or a constant sequence of $1$. You can easily obtain a bijection between these two countable sets by enumerating their elements.

Good job!

Comment: but $(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n)_{10}=(0.0\dot{1})_2$, isn't!!

Comment: This statement needs to be explained clearly. I think you're more or less saying that the generated set is dense in $2^\mathbb{N}$ in the sense of pointwise convergence. It remains that you are only generating a subset of $2^\mathbb{N}$, even if a dense one.

Comment: What if I just add this: "Note that $0.b_1b_2\dots b_k0111\dots=0.b_1b_2\dots b_k1000\dots$ for all $k\geq 1$ and $b_i\in \{0,1\}$, $i=1,\dots,k$"

Comment: Then we can get rid of the problem $\frac{n}{2^k}$ you mention, I guess!

Comment: A function associates a *single* image to each input value, so a function from $[0,1]$ to $2^\mathbb{N}$ cannot have two values for the same number $x$, for example $f(0.5)$ cannot be simultaneously the sequence $(1,0,0,...)$ and the sequence $(0,1,1,...)$, two distinct elements of $2^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: please check the answer now! I think it is complete now!

Comment: I think it's now correct. See my edit above.

Comment: Thanksss, I just could not ignore this and thought, "Nah! move to another problem. I will do this later". Your clarification helps me thinking that my whole evening was not wasted for nothing.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes your argument is wrong**.

In your algo, you start with $x = \frac{1}{2}$, do the $2x, \{2x\}$ computations. You end up adding $1$ and don't add anything else.

What is $a_1, a_2, \dots$? That is not part of your algo description and is in no way a proof that your algo works.

EDIT: Your $a_i$ only generate *finite* sets (call them $S_i$) and never the set (call that $S$) which Ross Millikan was talking about.

You generate a countable number of sets $S_i$ whose union is $S$, but never $S$.

The set corresponding to $\lim a_i$ is not $S$.

Comment: for the first line: What do you mean "end up adding $1$". $\{2x\}=0$. So you get $1,0,0,\dots$

Comment: @MANMAID: Yes, that is what I meant. You get $1, 0, 0, \dots$. Another way to look at it, you start with empty set $\phi$ and keep adding natural numbers to it, based on $2x \ge 1$ or not.

Comment: Ok, I understood what you want to say... the previous poster did not wanted a good algo... he wanted a contraction. So that was the  contraction I gave... so adding $0s$ again again is not a problem here!

Comment: @ManMAid. You are looking to map and $x$ to a set in $2^N$ isn't it? Maybe I misunderstood what you wrote.

Comment: No, map is $\mathbb{R}_{[0,1]}\rightarrow 2^{\mathbb{N}}$

Comment: That is what I said. There is too much confusion here.

Comment: for the second line: I introduced $a_,a_2,\dots$ to explain that $0,1,1,\dots$ is also can be generated... note that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0.5$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ gives $0,1,1,\dots$

Comment: @MANMAID: No. You only generate _finite_ sets by using the $a_i$, never the infinite set you are talking about. The limit of $a_i$ generates $1,0,0,\dots$, so you still haven't proved that $0,1,1\dots$ is generated.

Comment: So, one last question: Is this construction incomplete or totally wrong!!

Comment: There is a fine line between incomplete and wrong :-) You are close (considering binary representations) but need to tweak your algo.

Comment: What if I just add this: "Note that $0.b_1b_2\dots b_k0111\dots=0.b_1b_2\dots b_k1000\dots$, for all $k\geq 1$ and $b_i\in \{0,1\}$, $i=1,\dots,k$."

Comment: @MANMAID: Don't think that works.

Comment: please check the answer now! I think it is complete now!

Comment: @MANMAID: Why don't you just talk about the binary representation and picking a natural number if the corresponding bit is set to 1? Talking about "The Structure" unnecessarily complicates things. The tweak you made is not descriptive enough to tell, but I have a feeling you are getting close, though you should try to simplify a proof (for eg by demonstrating the x for sets which contain all naturals greater than a given one).

Comment: actually proving would not be a tough problem, but in the [main post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383021/inverse-mapping-from-mathbbr-to-subsets-of-mathbbn/2383056#2383056), OP wanted a construction of a bijective function. This is why I did this. Btw for the case of diyatic rationals will work!!! Everytime things just shifts one downward .... replicate itself... and $n/2^m$ can only have two representation $0.a_1a_2\dots a_k1_2$ and $0.a_1a_2\dots a_k0\dot{1}_2$

Answer (score 1):

I programmed a slight generalization of Manmaid's algorithm, as follows (with discussion and examples below that)...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
/* ==========================================================================
 * Function:    rtopown ( r, base, n )
 * Purpose:     Returns the first n most significant terms,
 *              i.e., n smallest "exponents",  in the "expansion"
 *              of real number r>=0 such that
 *                r = \sum_i=1^n (coefficient_i)/(base^exponent_i)
 *              with coefficients,exponents returned in the form
 *              x = { k_1, k_2, ..., k_n } subset N
 *              encoded in the k's as k_i = coefficient_i*1000 + exponent_i
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Arguments:   r (I)       double containing 0<=r<1 whose
 *                          representation is wanted
 *              base (i)    int containing "base" for expansion
 *              n (i)       int containing number of subset elements
 *              wanted
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Returns:    ( int * )    pointer to calloc()'ed array of int's
 *                          containing results, followed by -1.
 *                          If fewer than n required, e.g., r=0.5,base=2
 *                          returns {1001,-1}, then the -1 signals end.
 *                          Any error returns NULL pointer.
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Notes:     o See  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383021/
 *              for discussion.
 *            o caller should free() returned pointer after use.
 * ======================================================================= */
/* --- entry point --- */
int *rtopown ( double r, int base, int n ) {
  /* --- allocations and declarations --- */
  double rfrac = r;         /* iterated fractional part */
  int   rint  = 0,          /* integer part */
        expon = 0,          /* current base^expon exponent */
        nterms = 0,         /* #coefs,exponents saved in x[] */
        *x = NULL;          /* ptr to returned set of expons */
  /* --- initialization --- */
  if ( base < 2 ) goto end_of_job;       /* base out-of-bounds */
  if ( r < 0.0  ) goto end_of_job;       /* r out-of-bounds */
  if ( n<0 || n>255  ) goto end_of_job;  /* too many n requested */
  if ( (x = calloc(n+1,sizeof(int)))     /* allocate n+1 ints */
  ==   NULL ) goto end_of_job;           /* quit if calloc() failed */
  /* --- determine k_1,k_2,...,k_n --- */
  for ( expon=1; nterms<n; expon++ ) {   /* each power of base */
    rfrac *= base;                       /* multiply fractional part */
    if ( (rint = (int)(floor(rfrac)+0.1)) /* int part of multiplied frac */
    > 0 ) { x[nterms++] = 1000*rint + expon; /* save coefficient,exponent */
            rfrac -= (double)rint; }     /* save next fractional part */
    if ( rfrac <= 0.0 ) break; }         /* r "expansion" completed */
  /* --- end-of-job --- */
  x[nterms] = (-1);                      /* "trailer record" */
  end_of_job: return ( x );              /* back to caller */
  } /* --- end-of-function rtopown() --- */

/* ==========================================================================
 * Function:    main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
 * Purpose:     test driver for rtopown()
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Arguments:   argc        #command-line args
 *              argv[1]     r    (default: .375)
 *                          Note: r<0 uses -1/r, e.g., -3 for 1/3
 *              argv[2]     base (default: 2)
 *              argv[3]     n    (default: 24)
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Returns:     ( int )     always 0
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Notes:     o See  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383021/
 *              for discussion.
 * ======================================================================= */
/* --- entry point --- */
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  double r = ( argc>1? atof(argv[1]) : 0.375 );
  int base = ( argc>2? atoi(argv[2]) : 2     ),
         n = ( argc>3? atoi(argv[3]) : 24    );
  int   *rtopown(), *x = rtopown((r>=0.?r:-1.0/r),base,n), i=0;
  printf("rtopown(r=%.16f,base=%d,n=%d) =",r,base,n);
  if ( x != NULL ) while ( x[i] >= 0 ) {
    printf("%s%s%d/%d^%02d",(i%7==0?"\n  ":""),(i<1?"   ":" + "),
    x[i]/1000,base,x[i]%1000); i++; }
  printf("\n"); return ( 0 );
  } /* --- end-of-function main() --- */
/* --- end-of-file rtopown.c --- */
```

So a sample run of the form

```
bash-4.3$ ./rtopown .875 2
rtopown(r=0.8750000000000000,base=2,n=24) =
     1/2^01 + 1/2^02 + 1/2^03
```

just indicates that $0.875=\frac1{2^1}+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^3}$, or $(1,1,1,0,0,0,\ldots)$ in preceding notation. But that's just the default "*base $2$*", so to speak, which is that **2** on the command line.
We can also expand .875 in (inverse) powers of **3** or any other base, e.g.,

```
bash-4.3$ ./rtopown .875 3
rtopown(r=0.8750000000000000,base=3,n=24) =
     2/3^01 + 1/3^02 + 2/3^03 + 1/3^04 + 2/3^05 + 1/3^06 + 2/3^07
   + 1/3^08 + 2/3^09 + 1/3^10 + 2/3^11 + 1/3^12 + 2/3^13 + 1/3^14
   + 2/3^15 + 1/3^16 + 2/3^17 + 1/3^18 + 2/3^19 + 1/3^20 + 2/3^21
   + 1/3^22 + 2/3^23 + 1/3^24
```

which shows the first 24 terms of $.875=\frac2{3^1}+\frac1{3^2}+\frac2{3^3}+\cdots$. And in (inverse) powers of **4** we again get a simple form,

```
bash-4.3$ ./rtopown .875 4
rtopown(r=0.8750000000000000,base=4,n=24) =
     3/4^01 + 2/4^02
```

Note that only in "base 2" are the numerators always 1. Generally, they're $1\le\mbox{numerator}\le\mbox{base}-1$. Nevertheless, it's still entirely Manmaid's original algorithm. He simply checks $2x\ge1$, whereas I'm checking $\mbox{base}\times x\ge1$, and when it is I take that integer part as the numerator for the corresponding term in the expansion.

Now, as per the remarks concerning $(1,0,0,0,\ldots)$ versus $(0,1,1,1,\ldots)$, where some suggested Manmaid's algorithm couldn't generate the latter,...

```
bash-4.3$ ./rtopown .5 2  
rtopown(r=0.5000000000000000,base=2,n=24) =
     1/2^01
```

indeed corresponds to $(1,0,0,0,\ldots)$ (and rerunning it won't do anything different:). But

```
bash-4.3$ ./rtopown .499999999 2
rtopown(r=0.4999999990000000,base=2,n=24) =
     1/2^02 + 1/2^03 + 1/2^04 + 1/2^05 + 1/2^06 + 1/2^07 + 1/2^08
   + 1/2^09 + 1/2^10 + 1/2^11 + 1/2^12 + 1/2^13 + 1/2^14 + 1/2^15
   + 1/2^16 + 1/2^17 + 1/2^18 + 1/2^19 + 1/2^20 + 1/2^21 + 1/2^22
   + 1/2^23 + 1/2^24 + 1/2^25
```

does correspond to $(0,1,1,1,\ldots)$. So, it's just in the $\underset{x\to0.5}\lim x$ that you get $(1,0,0,0,\ldots)$ for that limit case $x=0.5$. But as you approach the limit you get $(0,1,1,1,\ldots)$ as closely as you like.

Comment: This is ok, but if you see the new version... you will see you actually do not have talk about limit etc. This version actually works perfectly for Dyatic rationals also!!! And you can achieve a bijcetive map only by slight change in your code.

Comment: @MANMAID Thanks. I didn't quite get it. First, why "n odd"? If n<2^m even, you can just keep dividing by 2 until it gets odd. Also, "fix f(1/2)=(1,1,1,...)" seems like it should be f(1/2)=(0,1,1,1,...)=1/4+1/8+etc. Ditto some of the subsequent "fixes". But I take it that you're constructing some different kind of correspondence to get your one-to-one bijection. However, I'm not quite seeing how that construction works. I understand the tree itself okay, but not how you're traversing your way down through it.

Comment: "you can just keep dividing by 2 until it gets odd"--- yes, you are right. But ultimately you are repeating a number again, that's all. Note that if you use all number of the form $n/2^m$, you may end up two different sequence of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ representing same dyatic rationals, which will violate the bijection. If you think a little bit, you will get that why I chose $n$ must be odd, if $n$ is also even numbers then you have to think a more complicated process.

Comment: fix f(1/2)=(1,1,1,...) required! Why? Bijection means inverse also exists. One important thing I was missing in the previous version is --- I was thinking is $0.1000\dots=0.0111\dots$ implies $(1,0,0,0,\dots)=(0,1,1,1,\dots)$, which is clearly not (ha ha!). So easily you can understand that $(\lim_{x\to 1} x)_{10}$ can not be $(1,1,1,\dots)$. That is why I fixed f(1/2)=(1,1,1,...). Similarly $(0.5)_{10}=(0.1)_2=(0.0\dot{1})_2$ (continuied)

Comment: Then $1/2$ will represent two sequences in $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ which are $(1,0,0,0,\dots)$ and $(0,1,1,1,\dots)$, which violates bijection. So I fixed $f(1/4)=(1,0,0,0,\dots)$ and $f(1/4)=(0,1,1,1,\dots)$. Note that there is no other rational numbers whose denominator contains $4$ (2/4=1/2, which is defined previously). Continue this process. Since there is countably infinite step in this process, you can map every dyatic rational uniquely (you can prove this actually, this is not tough). This is the beauty in this process.